# Object has no attribute error (Python code issue) - Outlook Global Address List information

Tags: python-3.x

---

```
    user = entry.GetExchangeUser()
    if user is not None:
        if len(user.FirstName) > 0 and len(user.LastName) > 0:
            row = list()
            row.append(date_id)
            row.append(user.Name)
            row.append(user.FirstName)
            row.append(user.LastName)
            row.append(user.JobTitle)
            row.append(user.City)
            row.append(user.PrimarySmtpAddress)
            row.append(user.OfficeLocation)
            row.append(user.Company)
            row.append(user.Department)
            row.append(user.Phone)
            row.append(user.Display)
            row.append(user.ZipCode)
            row.append(user.Assistant)
            row.append(user.CountryLocation)
            try:
              row.append(entry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3a26001e"))
            except:
```

### row.append('None')

I need it to show me the Company, Department, Phone, Display, Zipcode and Country location but I do not know what is wrong in the code. I can see name, office, location, city and address. The rest I am not able to.  Would someone help?  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Start by pasting the code here, and not it's image!

Comment: Well there are a bunch of things missing there. Like @DeveshKumarSingh already said, paste you code here with ` so we can read it properly and maybe paste the exception that you are getting so we can have a better understanding on what is really going on

Comment: Sorry. Here is a part of the code. It reads everything to ''user.OfficeLocation'' but the other attributes (Company,Department,Phone,Zip code etc) seem not to work.

Comment: Well, have you checked that each attribute exists for the user?

Comment: Yes they exist even if the tabs are blank

Comment: If a tab is "blank" then the attribute could be `= None`. Check it before appending it to the row.

Comment: Where should the = None be added in this situation? Sorry for the question

Comment: My point is that some attributes eg. `user.Department` may be `None`. That's why you're getting the error, you're trying to do `row.append(None)`. You need to check that each attribute is not `None` before appending it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. The script is going to be used for more than 15 people..i assume the attributes won't work in that case? Or is it possible to avoid the error message somehow?